# conditional rendering of components based on state change

Tags: reactjs

When a user enters a search item, if the data is available, then `<Pictures />` is displayed. If the data is not present then `<NoResultsFound />` is displayed.By default `<NoResultsFound />` state is false and `<Pictures />` is true because when the page loads the list of pictures are present. I tried to switch the state like this: `this.setState({uisNoResultsFound: true}) and this.setState({uisPictures: false})` throws syntax error. I want this conditional rendering of the UI states within app.js. How to do this?

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      uisSearchBarItems: true,
      uisNoResultsFound: false,
      uisPictures: true,
      dsPictures: []
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    unsplash.search.collections("frog", 1, 60)
    .then(toJson)
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({ dsPictures:json.results });
    })
  }


  enteredDatahandler = (ctp) => {
    unsplash.search.collections(ctp, 1, 60)
    .then(toJson)
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({ dsPictures:json.results })
    })

    //******** conditional rendering ***********
    if(this.state.dsPictures.length === 0){
      return (
        this.setState({uisNoResultsFound: true})
        this.setState({uisPictures: false})
      )
    }
    else{
      this.setState({uisNoResultsFound: false})
      this.setState({uisPictures: true})    
    }
    //***********************************

  }




  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBarItems ctpEnteredData={this.enteredDatahandler}/>
        <NoResultsFound />
        <Pictures ptcEnteredData={this.state.dsPictures}/>
      </div>
    );
   }
  }

export default App;
```

searchbaritems.js

```
class SearchBarItems extends Component {

  enterKeyHandler = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter'){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        this.props.ctpEnteredData(this.search.value)
    }
  }


 render() {
    return (
        <div>
           <form autoComplete="off" ref={(el) => this.myFormRef = el}>
           <input 
          type="text" 
          name="search" 
          ref={input => this.search = input}
          onKeyPress={this.enterKeyHandler}/>
          </form>
       </div>  
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning a `this.setstate()` in the conditional rendering section?

Comment: I'm new to react. Sorry. I want to show `<NoResultsFound /> ` if `this.state.dsPictures.length === 0`. Hence i was setting state within the if else statement.

Comment: I recommend trying the code without the return.

Comment: All the components are still visible on the dom, despite taking the return off.

Comment: Ok I think I found it. Inside your render() function for app.js, you are returning both components - meaning they will be rendered. You will need to put if statements in the render function to check whether  `uisNoResultsFound: false,
 uisPictures: true ` etc

Comment: I write the render function here: https://gist.github.com/tintinmovie/ed5b4782fa98c3482b561ea3243f98ea @Barazu 's answer is more cleaner, but is basically the simplified version of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ternary expression inside your render method.

```
{this.state.dsPictures.length === 0 ? <NoResultsFound /> :  <Pictures ptcEnteredData={this.state.dsPictures}/> }
```

Comment: If the OC goes with this, then the conditional rendering section of their code will be uncessary

Comment: To be more exact, this will be the conditional rendering.

Answer (score 1):

In your render function you are returning both components, you need to either have if statements or you can do what @Barazu did - which is the most cleanest code.

Github gist: https://gist.github.com/tintinmovie/ed5b4782fa98c3482b561ea3243f98ea

```
render() {
  if (this.state.uisNoResultsFound === true) {
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBarItems ctpEnteredData={this.enteredDatahandler}/>
        <NoResultsFound />
      </div>
    );
  }
  else if (this.state.uisPictures === true) {
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBarItems ctpEnteredData={this.enteredDatahandler}/>
        <Pictures ptcEnteredData={this.state.dsPictures}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```